# Sales Apex Error Message on a Line where nothing was changed

Tags: json, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

I got the following Error Message during deployment. The line where the Error occures, was never changed during editing.

> System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was
> expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:213, column:14]
> Stack Trace: (System Code) Class.OCRResponseWrapper.parse: line 96,
> column 1 Class.OCRServiceHandlerTest.testProcessOCRTickets: line 598,
> column 1

This is a shortend version

```
        String response = '{\n' +
                '  "api_request": {\n' +
                '    "error": {},\n' +
                '    "resources": [\n' +
                '      "document"\n' +
                '    ],\n' +
                '    "status": "success",\n' +
                '    "status_code": 201,\n' +
                '    "url": "link_to_api"\n' +
                '  },\n' +
                '  "document": {\n' +
                '    "annotations": {\n' +
                '      "labels": []\n' +
                '    },\n' +
                '    "id": "2664779a-3a9f-46f2-a464-5c7ecdfef886",\n' +
                '    "inference": {\n' +
                '      "extras": {},\n' +
                '      "finished_at": "2022-05-31T08:24:17+00:00",\n' +
                '      "pages": [\n' +
                '        {\n' +
                '          "extras": {},\n' +
                '          "id": 0,\n' +
                '          "prediction": {\n' +
                '            "authority": {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "values": [\n' +
                '                {\n' +
                '                  "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '                  "content": "string",\n' +
                '                  "polygon": [\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.6223,\n' +
                '                      0.9623\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.9431,\n' +
                '                      0.2612\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.08,\n' +
                '                      0.6763\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.12,\n' +
                '                      0.1751\n' +
                '                    ]\n' +
                '                  ]\n' +
                '                }\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            },\n' +
                '            "fine_category": {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "values": [\n' +
                '                {\n' +
                '                  "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '                  "content": "ANONYMVERFUGUNG",\n' +
                '                  "polygon": [\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.8061,\n' +
                '                      0.3567\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.4201,\n' +
                '                      0.9075\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.7176,\n' +
                '                      0.3005\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.2901,\n' +
                '                      0.9953\n' +
                '                    ]\n' +
                '                  ]\n' +
                '                }\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            },\n' +
                '            "fine_date_time": {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "values": [\n' +
                '                {\n' +
                '                  "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '                  "content": "string",\n' +
                '                  "polygon": [\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.7343,\n' +
                '                      0.4254\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.2391,\n' +
                '                      0.6612\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.5813,\n' +
                '                      0.4651\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.6642,\n' +
                '                      0.0535\n' +
                '                    ]\n' +
                '                  ]\n' +
                '                }\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            },\n' +
                '            "fine_type": {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "values": [\n' +
                '                {\n' +
                '                  "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '                  "content": "string",\n' +
                '                  "polygon": [\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.2811,\n' +
                '                      0.503\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.5495,\n' +
                '                      0.0628\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.6965,\n' +
                '                      0.011\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.3931,\n' +
                '                      0.8666\n' +
                '                    ]\n' +
                '                  ]\n' +
                '                }\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            },\n' +
                '            "license_plate": {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "values": [\n' +
                '                {\n' +
                '                  "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '                  "content": "string",\n' +
                '                  "polygon": [\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.8085,\n' +
                '                      0.1184\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.5322,\n' +
                '                      0.7751\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.5778,\n' +
                '                      0.3133\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.9082,\n' +
                '                      0.7193\n' +
                '                    ]\n' +
                '                  ]\n' +
                '                }\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            },\n' +
                '            "link_for_driver_identification": {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "values": [\n' +
                '                {\n' +
                '                  "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '                  "content": "string",\n' +
                '                  "polygon": [\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.381,\n' +
                '                      0.9487\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.8849,\n' +
                '                      0.6386\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.8069,\n' +
                '                      0.3403\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.0637,\n' +
                '                      0.569\n' +
                '                    ]\n' +
                '                  ]\n' +
                '                }\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            },\n' +
                '            "location": {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "values": [\n' +
                '                {\n' +
                '                  "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '                  "content": "string",\n' +
                '                  "polygon": [\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.2361,\n' +
                '                      0.5289\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.4005,\n' +
                '                      0.9247\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.4554,\n' +
                '                      0.3263\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.5909,\n' +
                '                      0.7414\n' +
                '                    ]\n' +
                '                  ]\n' +
                '                }\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            }\n' +
                '            "authority_email": {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "values": [\n' +
                '                {\n' +
                '                  "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '                  "content": "string",\n' +
                '                  "polygon": [\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.594,\n' +
                '                      0.23\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.782,\n' +
                '                      0.232\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.782,\n' +
                '                      0.24\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.594,\n' +
                '                      0.238\n' +
                '                    ]\n' +
                '                  ]\n' +
                '                }\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            }\n' +
                '            "authority_reference": {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "values": [\n' +
                '                {\n' +
                '                  "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '                  "content": "string",\n' +
                '                  "polygon": [\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.174,\n' +
                '                      0.113\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.212,\n' +
                '                      0.113\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.212,\n' +
                '                      0.122\n' +
                '                    ],\n' +
                '                    [\n' +
                '                      0.174,\n' +
                '                      0.122\n' +
                '                    ]\n' +
                '                  ]\n' +
                '                }\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            }\n' +
                '          }\n' +
                '        }\n' +
                '      ],\n' +
                '      "prediction": {\n' +
                '        "authority": {\n' +
                '          "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '          "page_id": 0,\n' +
                '          "values": [\n' +
                '            {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "content": "string",\n' +
                '              "polygon": [\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.9915,\n' +
                '                  0.6867\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.3138,\n' +
                '                  0.556\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.4087,\n' +
                '                  0.9454\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.065,\n' +
                '                  0.1378\n' +
                '                ]\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            }\n' +
                '          ]\n' +
                '        },\n' +
                '        "fine_category": {\n' +
                '          "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '          "page_id": 0,\n' +
                '          "values": [\n' +
                '            {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "content": "ANONYMVERFUGUNG",\n' +
                '              "polygon": [\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.936,\n' +
                '                  0.4821\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.3597,\n' +
                '                  0.0843\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.6884,\n' +
                '                  0.8568\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.3417,\n' +
                '                  0.1877\n' +
                '                ]\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            }\n' +
                '          ]\n' +
                '        },\n' +
                '        "fine_date_time": {\n' +
                '          "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '          "page_id": 0,\n' +
                '          "values": [\n' +
                '            {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "content": "string",\n' +
                '              "polygon": [\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.1522,\n' +
                '                  0.6463\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.5195,\n' +
                '                  0.5938\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.0634,\n' +
                '                  0.7891\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.7832,\n' +
                '                  0.4485\n' +
                '                ]\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            }\n' +
                '          ]\n' +
                '        },\n' +
                '        "fine_type": {\n' +
                '          "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '          "page_id": 0,\n' +
                '          "values": [\n' +
                '            {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "content": "string",\n' +
                '              "polygon": [\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.5954,\n' +
                '                  0.1722\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.8358,\n' +
                '                  0.6238\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.833,\n' +
                '                  0.4692\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.3512,\n' +
                '                  0.0749\n' +
                '                ]\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            }\n' +
                '          ]\n' +
                '        },\n' +
                '        "license_plate": {\n' +
                '          "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '          "page_id": 0,\n' +
                '          "values": [\n' +
                '            {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "content": "string",\n' +
                '              "polygon": [\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.2866,\n' +
                '                  0.112\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.0644,\n' +
                '                  0.6146\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.0885,\n' +
                '                  0.4038\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.7936,\n' +
                '                  0.87\n' +
                '                ]\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            }\n' +
                '          ]\n' +
                '        },\n' +
                '        "link_for_driver_identification": {\n' +
                '          "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '          "page_id": 0,\n' +
                '          "values": [\n' +
                '            {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "content": "string",\n' +
                '              "polygon": [\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.6128,\n' +
                '                  0.5198\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.1134,\n' +
                '                  0.3069\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.5099,\n' +
                '                  0.5496\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.1741,\n' +
                '                  0.9287\n' +
                '                ]\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            }\n' +
                '          ]\n' +
                '        },\n' +
                '        "location": {\n' +
                '          "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '          "page_id": 0,\n' +
                '          "values": [\n' +
                '            {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "content": "string",\n' +
                '              "polygon": [\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.8304,\n' +
                '                  0.1977\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.8948,\n' +
                '                  0.1731\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.1162,\n' +
                '                  0.7091\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.0559,\n' +
                '                  0.965\n' +
                '                ]\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            }\n' +
                '          ]\n' +
                '        }\n' +
                '        "authority_email": {\n' +
                '          "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '          "page_id": 0,\n' +
                '          "values": [\n' +
                '            {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "content": "string",\n' +
                '              "polygon": [\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.594,\n' +
                '                  0.23\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.782,\n' +
                '                  0.232\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.782,\n' +
                '                  0.24\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.594,\n' +
                '                  0.238\n' +
                '                ]\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            }\n' +
                '          ]\n' +
                '        }\n' +
                '        "authority_reference": {\n' +
                '          "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '          "page_id": 0,\n' +
                '          "values": [\n' +
                '            {\n' +
                '              "confidence": 0.99,\n' +
                '              "content": "string",\n' +
                '              "polygon": [\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.174,\n' +
                '                  0.113\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.212,\n' +
                '                  0.113\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.212,\n' +
                '                  0.122\n' +
                '                ],\n' +
                '                [\n' +
                '                  0.174,\n' +
                '                  0.122\n' +
                '                ]\n' +
                '              ]\n' +
                '            }\n' +
                '          ]\n' +
                '        }\n' +
                '      },\n' +
                '      "processing_time": 1.919,\n' +
                '      "product": {\n' +
                '           "features": [\n' +
                '               "license_plate",\n' +
                '               "fine_date_time",\n' +
                '               "fine_type",\n' +
                '               "authority",\n' +
                '               "location",\n' +
                '               "link_for_driver_identification",\n' +
                '               "fine_category",\n' +
                '               "authority_email",\n' +
                '               "authority_reference"\n' +
                '           ],\n' +
                '        "name": "api_name",\n' +
                '        "version": "1.4"\n' +
                '      },\n' +
                '      "started_at": "datetime"\n' +
                '    },\n' +
                '    "n_pages": 1,\n' +
                '    "name": "myfile.jpg",\n' +
                '    "ocr": {}\n' +
                '  }\n' +
                '}';
```

I just added authority_email and authority_reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
}\n' +
 "authority_email": {\n' +
```

There should be a comma after `}`, before the `"authority"`.
Same with `"authority_reference"`.

And pay attention, you injected them in few places so gotta check/fix them all.